# precondition <sqlcheck> is not working for schema

Tags: liquibase

I want to have "IF NOT EXIST" functionality for my schema creation in Oracle.
I am using liquibase for ddl and spring boot application.

```
<changeSet author="admin" id="1">
<preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
<sqlCheck expectedResult="0">SELECT COUNT(1) FROM dba_users WHERE USERNAME='abc'</sqlCheck>
</preConditions>
    <sql dbms="oracle" endDelimiter=";">
        CREATE USER abc IDENTIFIED BY abc DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS QUOTA UNLIMITED ON USERS TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP QUOTA 5M ON system PROFILE DEFAULT
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

This is not working. But without `<precondition>` user is created, but I need 'IF NOT EXIST' 
Can anyone help me here.

Thanks
Senthil

Comment: Usernames are stored in UPPERCASE, did you try: `WHERE USERNAME='ABC'`? But requiring  DBA privileges for your setup is not really a good idea. I know a lot of environments where this would be flat out rejected. Creating users is typically only done by the DBA and she/he will also control the assignment of tablespaces and quotas.

Comment: Yes, I tried with Upper Case, but not successful.  We are writing a micro service in spring boot so that we want to have separate schema for our micro service which will be created / initialized with in our service.

Comment: Its my mistake.  ChangeSet is executing after adding the property runAlways=true. 

I am using SpringBoot application, so I will restart and check the application often.  So, without runAlways it is expected behaviour . Now it is fine.